# How to save added items to combobox between sessions?

Tags: c#, wpf

I added items to a combobox using a textbox and button:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
}
```

I am unsure how to save the items added to the combobox for use in another session. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You need some sort of database to read, create, update and delete data.

Comment: As a simple alternative without using a database, you can write the inserted data to a .txt file. You can save this .txt file anywhere on the computer. You can read this .txt file every time you open an application and fill in the relevant fields. If the data is too much, using a database would be a better solution.

Comment: A bad solution, but as a different approach; You can define a string in the Properties.Settings field. Each time new data is added, you can add the data to this string by separating with . You read this value you defined at every application start. You can view what their values are by separating them with a comma. A very different solution :)

Comment: The file method should suffice for my needs. Using XamlWriter/Reader almost works but when I load after saving, none of the buttons work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the values to a file:

```cs
private async Task SaveComboBoxToFileAsync()
{
  await using var file = File.OpenWrite("box_values.txt");
  using var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(file);

  foreach (var textValue in this.comboBox.Items.Cast<string>())
  {
    await fileWriter.WriteLineAsync(textValue);
  }
}

private async Task InitializeComboBoxFromFileAsync()
{
  var values = new List<string>();

  if (File.Exists("box_values.txt"))
  {
    await using var file = File.OpenRead("box_values.txt");
    using var fileReader = new StreamReader(file);

    while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
    {
      string textValue = await fileReader.ReadLineAsync();
      values.Add(textValue);
    }
  }

  this.comboBox.ItemsSource = values;
}
```

### Usage example

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservablCollection<string> ComboBoxValues { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    
    this.DataContext = this;

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    this.ComboBoxValues = new ObservablCollection<string>();
  }

  private async void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    await InitializeComboBoxFromFileAsync();
  }
    
  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ComboBoxValues.Add(this.InputTextBox.Text);
    await SaveComboBoxToFileAsync();
  }

  private async Task SaveComboBoxToFileAsync()
  {
    await using var file = File.OpenWrite("box_values.txt");
    using var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(file);

    foreach (string textValue in this.ComboBoxValues)
    {
      await fileWriter.WriteLineAsync(textValue);
    }
  }

  private async Task InitializeComboBoxFromFileAsync()
  {
    if (File.Exists("box_values.txt"))
    {
      this.ComboBoxValues.Clear();

      await using var file = File.OpenRead("box_values.txt");
      using var fileReader = new StreamReader(file);

      while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
      {
        string textValue = await fileReader.ReadLineAsync();
        this.ComboBoxValues.Add(textValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox" />
    <Button Content="Add" 
            Click="Button_Click" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxValues}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it works great up to the point I need to add another item to the combobox. Any ideas how I can add another item to the combobox when using this code to read/write to file?

Comment: Usually you would add the new item to a ObservableCollection that is bound to the ComboBox.ItemsSource. You can call SaveComboBoxToFileAsync() this moment or wait until e.g., your application shuts down.  Manipulate the ComboBox and then call SaveComboBoxToFileAsync afterwards.

Comment: If you bind to an ObservableCollection, you can save this collection directly rather than the ComboBox.ItemsSource. This is more elegant.

Comment: According to your posted code, you must call `SaveComboBoxToFileAsync()` in your button event handler `Button_Click` after adding the new item.

Comment: I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example usage, I'm getting this error when adding the item: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

Comment: I was just copy&pasting your code assuming that you were already using it. I have updated the complete example to give you something that compiles (only add the required namespaces and the x:Class attribute to the `Window` XAML element in the MainWindow.xaml file. Copy the complete MainWindow.xaml.cs file from the example.

Comment: Thanks for that I would upvote if I had enough reputation; very much appreciated.